GDB 'section' command doesn't seem to work as expected
As I understand it, the section command can be used to tell gdb that a specific section of the object file is loaded in a specific address. In my understanding this should also entail relocating all symbols in that section to the new address (otherwise, what's the point?)
However, it doesn't seem to do that. Let's show it with a dummy program, a.c:
void func(void)
{
}

int main()
{
}

Compile it with gcc -g a.c
Then under gdb ./a.out
(gdb) pipe info files | grep .text
    0x0000000000001040 - 0x0000000000001143 is .text

(gdb) mt info sections .text
Exec file: `/******/a.out', file type elf64-x86-64.
 [13]     0x00001040->0x00001143 at 0x00001040: .text ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS

(gdb) info address func
Symbol "func" is a function at address 0x1129.

(gdb) info symbol 0x1129
func in section .text

(gdb) section .text 0x100000
------
    0x0000000000100000 - 0x0000000000100103 is .text
------

# However:
(gdb) mt info sections .text
Exec file: `/*******/a.out', file type elf64-x86-64.
 [13]     0x00001040->0x00001143 at 0x00001040: .text ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS

# Calculate relocated address 
(gdb) p/x 0x1129-0x1040+0x100000
$1 = 0x1000e9

(gdb) info symbol 0x1000e9
No symbol matches 0x1000e9.

(gdb) info address func
Symbol "func" is a function at address 0x1129.

What is happening here? Why is the output of mt info sections different from info files? Why does func retain its old address? what did my section command actually do?
BTW, when I use add-symbol-file ./a.out -s .text 0x100000 it does to the extra symbol file exactly what I expect section to do.
I'm using gdb version 12.1 on an ubuntu 22.04 machine, if it is at all relevant
I would appreciate any help :)
